# Django queryset (filter) based on user logged and foreign key other model

Tags: django, filter

Here is my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Order(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
     order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     schedule = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

views.py:

```
def order_list(request):
     orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(id__product=id, product_id=Product.objects.filter(created_by=request.user))
     return render(request, 'orders/order/order_list.html', {'orders': orders})
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="text-center logo my-4">
        <a>Queue List</a>
    </h4>
    <div>
        <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Birth Date</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for order in orders %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ order.order.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ order.order.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ order.order.birth_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ order.order.age }}</td>
                <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" role="button">Add</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>  
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm new to Django. I'd like to create view based on user who created the product. So when that user logs in to the web they can see the order item list.

Here is the error message:

> Unsupported lookup 'product' for AutoField or join on the field not
>   permitted.

Comment: This is almost a question, you should also provide the template to show what you've tried and specifically ask what has gone amiss.  For information on users in django see the `auth` module https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: Hello, and welcome to _StackOverflow_! Its a **great** community! I think you may benefit from a [really good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions here. More information is needed for others to help you. Good luck!

Comment: I got error message: Unsupported lookup 'product' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `in` operator for your query filter instead of an exact match:

```
orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(product_id__in=Product.objects.filter(created_by=request.user))
```

Comment: I see. Did not notice that you had an unnecessary `id__product=id` filter. Fixed by removing it then.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```